# How can I get Exception or Throwable in ACRA custom sender

Tags: android, acra

Hi I need to send crash reports to Airbrake but I belive that ACRA is much more powerful tool for this purpose on android platform so I've been trying to combine both of them and implement my own `ReposrtSender` for ACRA which do `AirbrakeNotifier.notify();`. Unfortunately it requires an Exception as a parameter but `send()` method provide only `CrashReportData`.

```
public interface ReportSender {
    /**
     * Send crash report data. You don't have to take care of managing Threads,
     * just implement what is necessary to handle the data. ACRA will use a
     * specific Thread (not the UI Thread) to run your sender.
     * 
     * @param errorContent
     *            Stores key/value pairs for each report field. A report field
     *            is identified by a {@link ReportField} enum value.
     * @throws ReportSenderException
     *             If anything goes fatally wrong during the handling of crash
     *             data, you can (should) throw a {@link ReportSenderException}
     *             with a custom message.
     */

    public void send(CrashReportData errorContent) throws ReportSenderException;
}
```

Here is my implementation of sender which should send report to Airbrake:

```
public class MyReportSender implements ReportSender {
    public void send(CrashReportData errorContent) throws ReportSenderException {
        AirbrakeNotifier.notify(/*Exception is required here*/);
        // But only key/value pairs are available here in errorContent param.
    }
}
```

I noticed that I can construct a new exception with some data from `CrashReporData` but it's much better to get the original one if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is old I still want to answer it as I found it via google and others might do that too.

---

It is impossible to get the `Exception` inside a `ReportSender`. You can get its stacktrace, but not the object itself (because it lives in a different process than your sender and is at this point probably already garbage collected).

If you need the object, you could use a `ReportPrimer` instead. It is called before the report is built and thus has access to the `ReportBuilder`, which carries the `Exception` object (among other data as e.g. the crashed `Thread`).

Answer (score 0):

Place ACRA jar file inside libs directory in your project and create CrashReport.java file

```
@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "http://www.bugsense.com/api/acra?api_key=6f3855c9", formKey="")
//api_key you will get once you register your application with ACRA.

public class CrashReport extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // The following line Application register with ACRA
    ACRA.init(this);
}
}
```

Set your crash report class inside application tag inside menifest.xml file like this

```
android:name="com.example.mydoc.CrashReport"
```

here com.example.mydoc is application package where your crash report reside.

Comment: and where is an exception ?

Comment: This is way you can register your project with ACRA for collecting exception information. if you want exception in any class you can parse null value in integer it will through exception on ACRA

Comment: Unfortunately it does not help me any way. The question is about Excetion in custom sender not about registration ACRA in project. Thanks for your attempt.

Comment: if you want to know your exception ACRA is the best solution but I hope It is free for a month